# Free MySQL synchronization tool

Tags: mysql, synchronization

does anybody know some free tool for synchronization MySQL database (data and structure) like in [Navicat](http://mysql.navicat.com/) for Windows ?

---

I'm using Structure and Data synchronization. Sometimes Data transfer. I was just wondering if there is not any software like this for free. Found only HeidiSQL (which looks perfect but work worse).

Comment: Just a word of warning for those downloading version 5.2.31 alpha, the software develops a sync problem after a while.

Comment: hi i have the same problem. i would like to sync a local database on windows os to remote mysql server on debian as a scheduled job. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155889/sync-local-microsoft-mysql-database-to-remote-mysql-database-scheduled-daily

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench Beta](http://wb.mysql.com/) does this perfectly and for free for now.

Answer (score 4):

You can just try **dbForge Studio for MySQL**  to sync mysql databases. This tool  provides a number of  features that help you with mysql synchronization:

- MySQL sync tools allows you to compare quickly MySQL schema and data
- Review differences, apply groups and  filters
- Apply more than one synchronization ways to choose from
- Well-tested functionality, created by developers for developers and
  DBAs

There is free 30-days usage of the MySQL sync tools in a [dbForge Studio trial](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html).

Comment: -1 for "dbForge studio trial " not being a free tool. Trial versions are not considered free tools

Answer (score 3):

If you just want synchronization would MySQL replication work for you?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Replication is not synchronizing data. Its overwrite data.

Answer (score 3):

Percona Toolkit (formerly Maatkit) has a tool for this ....

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use MySQL Workbench. It has sync feaures, which is great. I use 2 different servers (dev and prod) and of course the EER Model. I sync the model with the development database, and then I sync the prod database with my model.

Answer (score 1):

[Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) has synchronization abilities and is free.

Answer (score 0):

What functionality of Navicat do you need?  There is a number of ways without that software to synchronize mysql.  You can use the MySQL replication functionality or simply copy and paste the data files (if your using MyISAM tables it's just a straight copy) innoDB tables are a little more tricky.