# How do I do an incremental backup for a mysql database using a .sql file?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Situation: our production mysql database makes a daily dump into a .sql file.  I'd like to keep a shadow database that is relatively up to date.
I know that to create a mysql database from a .sql file, one uses:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASENAME < FILE.SQL
```

For our db, this took 4-5 hours.  Needless to say, I'd like to cut that down, and I'm wondering if there's a way to just update the db with what's new/changed.  On Day 2, is there a way to just *update* my shadow database with the new .sql file dumped from the production db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Replication is the way to go.

**But, in cases, where that is not possible, use the following procedure**:

Have a modifed timestamp column in all your tables and update this value whenever a row is inserted/changed.

Use the following mysqldump options to take the **incremental SQL file** (this uses REPLACE commands instead of insertcommands, since the existing record will be updated in the backup database).

Keep a timestamp value somewhere placed in the file system. and use it in the where condition. MDFD_DATE is the column name on which you need to filter. On successful backup, update the value stored in the file.

skip-tz-utc prevents MSQL from automatically adjusting the timestamp values, based on your timezone.

> mysqldump --databases db1,db2 --user=user --password=password  --no-create-info --no-tablespaces --replace --skip-tz-utc --lock-tables --add-locks --compact --where=MDFD_DATE>='2012-06-13 23:09:42' --log-error=dump_error.txt --result-file=result.sql

Use the new sql file and run it in your server.

**Limitations:**

This method will not work if some records are deleted in your database. You need to manually delete them from the backup databases. Otherwise, keep a DEL_FLAG column and update it to 'Y' in production for deleted records and use this condition to delete records in the backup databases.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using  `mysql` synchronization.

Comment: Does this cause a load on the master server - sending a copy of every op to the slave? I was planning on using the daily dumps because it would have zero effect on the master.

Comment: no it would start from the point where you had stopped.Please refer this link [link](http://rdkls.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/adding-new-database-to-running-mysql.html)

Answer (score 1):

Some links to guide you:

- http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication
- [Free MySQL synchronization tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364291/free-mysql-synchronization-tool)
- https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy
- https://www.google.com.br/search?q=mysql+synchronization

Comment: Answers which contain only links are not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Your answer needs to stand alone, and should retain its meaning even if all external links are removed.