# Sync Local Microsoft MySQL database to remote mysql database scheduled daily

Tags: mysql, sql, database, synchronization, scheduled-tasks

Hi i have a local mysql database that gets updated locally daily on windows machine. at the end of the day, i want a scheduled job to be called by windows that updates a remote mysql database with all the the new data ie compare and synchronize.

i have already created the test database on remote server and ive allowed remote access. i want simple program/solution that i could call on command line that updates remote database with new or changed records etc.

the local database is on a windows machine and remote database is on a webserver with debian.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows replication: you wouldnt need to use a specific app, have you looked at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: im not sure if its what im looking for. and that link doesnt explain how to solve my problem without confusing me.