# Ideas for synchronizing records programmatically

Tags: php, mysql, database, synchronization

I need to synchronize records, say a list of clients, between a local and distant database. The database on both sides has the same structure. I've thought of using some kind of marker (date field, hash/checksum on field values...) but what would you advise ?

Edit: Distant database is on web hosting so PHP will be needed for transferring data.

Comment: Most databases have some form of replication mechanism that allows you to keep multiple copies of the database synchronised - what flavour of database are you using?

Comment: If you are using MySQL, check this then:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364291/free-mysql-synchronization-tool

Comment: @MarkBaker MySQL. Direct connection (port 3306?) might not be possible as the distant database would be on web hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to have a last change field (date) on your records. Keep in mind that, if you start to synchronize, you have to take care of conflicts.

If both sides can insert, use a partitioning scheme for your primary keys. Example: Site A starts from 1000000000, Site B from 2000000000 (make this numbers large enough or simply divide your primary key size by the number of concurrent sites).

**Rough synchronize plot:**

1. Get the modified records from source A, beginning from the last sync cycle.
2. For each record, check:

   1. Is it newly inserted in A? Then insert it in B
   2. Is it modified in A, but not in B: update B
   3. Is it modified in A and in B: resolve conflicts on a field level.
3. Get the modified records from source B, beginning from the last sync cycle
4. For each record, check:

   1. Is it newly inserted in B? Then insert it in A
   2. Is it modified in B, but not in A: update A
   3. Is it modified in B and in A: resolve conflicts on a field level.

Comment: how to handle concurrent inserts on site A with own primary key generation?

Comment: You don't need to handle the primary key generation by your own - you can use different auto_increment key offsets on both sites.

Comment: About PKs, perhaps something like an added client id could be used to make the local and distant table correspond.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sync two databases by code, you're looking for trouble.

First of all, you need to handle your own primary key generation, because when inserting records on different sites, primary keys can/will be the same. Unique primary key generation is not easy to accomplish.

Furthermore, you need some conflict resolution. Updates or Deletes made on either side have to be reflected to the other site. Often, you cannot solve conflicts without user intervention.

My advise: look at built-in (two-way) replication, native to the database. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Yes, thinking of it in those terms ids could be problematic. Perhaps concentrating on the information itself would be better advised than actually syncing the records themselves. That would still leave the possibility of conflicts.